# Django - CheckboxSelectMultiple shows object representation instead of object's name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I am trying to have a list of checkboxes of cities, but instead of showing the cities' name, it shows this:

[image: Wrong print]

How to make it shows the name instead of `City object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you have to include **__str__** for python3 and **unicode** for python 2

For example python 3:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Python 2

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like charm!

Comment: No problem. You can mark as an answer mate. Best wishes.

Comment: Should wait for 10 minutes. Will do soon