# Many to Many relation' list display with checkbox in Django

Tags: django

[image: it is Doctor update form with associated Clinic/Hospital list.]

I want a checkbox with the M2M list of Clinic/Hospital with an individual row.
here are my forms

```
class ClinicHospitalForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta():
     model = ClinicHospital
     fields = ('name','address','contact','lat','lon')

class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = Doctor
    fields = ('name','speciality','contact','clinic_hospital')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the widget to a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):

```
class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name','speciality','contact','clinic_hospital')
        widgets = {
            'clinic_hospital': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

Comment: it shows just checkbox. I want list along with checkbox on each row of list.

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed: no normally it shows one checkbox per item (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449472/django-checkboxselectmultiple-shows-object-representation-instead-of-objects?rq=1). It looks like the css might mix it up.

Comment: fine when list is going long then it will look strange.

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed: no, you just wrap it in a scrollable container; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280389/scrollable-box-containing-list-of-checkboxes-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) .For example if `clinic_hospital` is your ManyToMany field and you want to display it as a checkbox then you can try like this

```
class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    clinic_hospital= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta():
       model = Doctor
       fields = ('name','speciality','contact','clinic_hospital')
```